# Teradata Oracle Wire Protocol ODBC connection test error, specified driver could not be loaded

Tags: oracle, teradata

I am trying to test my ODBC connection in Teradata on UNIX using adhoc file.

```
teradata/client/17.10/odbc_64/samples/C/adhoc
```

when trying to connect to Oracle DSN, I get following error

```
 adhoc: (SQL Diagnostics) STATE=IM003, CODE=0, MSG=[DataDirect][ODBC lib] Specifi                                                                                                                                                      ed driver could not be loaded
    No driver entry found under the DSN :
```

I have the entries in
odbc.ini as

```
[BIC_DEV_ORA_TW]
Description=Teradata 8.0 Oracle Wire Protocol
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/17.10/tbuild/odbc/lib64/_Tora28.so
AlternateServers=
ApplicationUsingThreads=1
AccountingInfo=
Action=
ApplicationName=
ArraySize=60000
AuthenticationMethod=1
BulkBinaryThreshold=32
BulkCharacterThreshold=-1
BulkLoadBatchSize=1024
BulkLoadFieldDelimiter=
BulkLoadRecordDelimiter=
CachedCursorLimit=32
CachedDescLimit=0
CatalogIncludesSynonyms=1
CatalogOptions=0
ClientHostName=
ClientID=
ClientUser=
ConnectionReset=0
ConnectionRetryCount=0
ConnectionRetryDelay=3
```

Comment: The odbcinst.ini describes the installed drivers, the odbc.ini describes data sources using those drivers. The driver manager is complaining about not finding the DSN in odbc.ini file. If you can't figure out the issue yourself, edit your question to include the relevant information (and possibly reformat the odbcinst.ini entries to have proper line breaks).

Comment: Hi, The DSN is present in odbc.ini
`code`

[BIC_DEV_ORA_TW]
Description=Teradata 8.0 Oracle Wire Protocol
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/17.10/tbuild/odbc/lib64/_Tora28.so
AlternateServers=
ApplicationUsingThreads=1
AccountingInfo=
Action=
ApplicationName=
ArraySize=60000
AuthenticationMethod=1
BulkBinaryThreshold=32
BulkCharacterThreshold=-1
BulkLoadBatchSize=1024
BulkLoadFieldDelimiter=
BulkLoadRecordDelimiter=
CachedCursorLimit=32
CachedDescLimit=0
CatalogIncludesSynonyms=1
CatalogOptions=0
ClientHostName=
ClientID=
ClientUser=
ConnectionReset=0

Comment: Is ODBCINI environment variable set to point to the odbc.ini? And you are using BIC_DEV_ORA_TW as the DSN for `adhoc` program? Edit the question to include the odbc.ini entry so you can format it properly.

Comment: Hi Fred,
I changed the question to include ODBC.ini content, also the environment variable of the user is set to use this odbc.ini file.

Comment: Does odbc.ini also include an entry under the `[ODBC Data Sources]` key something like `BIC_DEV_ORA_TW=Teradata 8.0 Oracle Wire Protocol`?

Comment: Yes, it does.at the beginning.